# Listbox selected event firing automatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I've a winform and I'm trying to bind some elements at page load method. After that

listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event fires automatically. Why it is happening?

Thanks in advance,
Nagu

Answer (score 4):

I assume that this is because your list box begins life with no items in it (so its SelectedIndex property is -1). As soon as it's populated, its SelectedIndex property changes to 0 (to select the first item in the now populated list box) and then SelectedIndexChanged event is now fired.

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt get your point. Can you give me a simple example code line?

Answer (score 1):

disable the event prior to binding:

listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

re-enable after binding:

listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;